# pgfplot barchart moving x-axis up

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

For the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ylabel={Time Elapsed (in hours)},
xlabel={Methods},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
width=0.8*\textwidth,
height=9cm,
bar width=7pt,
symbolic x coords={Category-1,Category-2,Category-3},
xtick=data,
%nodes near coords,
%nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,0.14) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,13.25)};
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,2.76) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,29.55)};
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,2.81) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,16.04)};
        \legend{byHalf, Random, Hybrid}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I make my x-label move up so that it touches the bars ?

[image]

Comment: Adding `ymin=0` to the `axis` options seems to do the job.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes this is actually what I needed to achieve thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a discrepancy between the title and the question in the body. I am answering the question posed in the title.

If you add `ymin=0` to the `axis` you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ylabel={Time Elapsed (in hours)},
xlabel={Methods},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
width=0.8*\textwidth,
height=9cm,
bar width=7pt,
symbolic x coords={Category-1,Category-2,Category-3},
xtick=data,
%nodes near coords,
%nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,0.14) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,13.25)};
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,2.76) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,29.55)};
        \addplot
        coordinates {(Category-1,2.81) (Category-2,2) (Category-3,16.04)};
        \legend{byHalf, Random, Hybrid}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```