# left-justified text in the same line as the beginning of \align equations

Tags: align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate)
>   [How to split and align equations when they are inside an enumerate environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68231/how-to-split-and-align-equations-when-they-are-inside-an-enumerate-environment)
>   [pgfplot barchart moving x-axis up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69231/pgfplot-barchart-moving-x-axis-up)

I want to start a line with something easy as "a)" as left-justified text. But I want to have the beginning of `\align` equations on that same line. But, of course, if I use the `\align` order it jumps automatically in a new line and starts there with the first equation. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Related question: [Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394/3323)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe this question and answer help? [How to split and align equations when they are inside an enumerate environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68231/12850)

Comment: You could put the `a)` in the align anvironment via `\begin{align} \text{a)} <mathcontent> \end{align}`